# How to add an option to the right-click menu

Tags: javascript

I'm going to make a plugin that performs an action on the page. I need a new item to be added when the user right-clicks on the page, like some of the plugins I'm taking a picture of.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hSEP.png)

**I want to do this with javascript.**

```
function onContextMenu(event) {
  // Add a new context menu item
  event.menu.items.push({
    label: "Right-Align",
    click: function() {
      // Do something
    }
  });

  // Return the modified menu
  return event.menu.items;
}

// Add the context menu listener
document.body.addEventListener("contextmenu", onContextMenu);
```

```
I tried this line of code but it didn't work.
```

Comment: I think for security reasons you cannot do this. But I am very interested if anyone else has a solution!

Comment: What is `event.menu.items`, where did you get that from?